# $S \circ (T + U) = S \circ T + S \circ U$

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $S, T$ and $U$ be linear maps $V \longrightarrow V$ .Proving that $(S\circ T)\circ U = S\circ (T\circ U)$and $S \circ (T + U) = S \circ T + S  \circ U$ will require what series of steps?What is the trick here?

Comment: Two linear maps $A$ and $B$ are equal iff $Av=Bv$ for all $v\in V$. So that's what you want to show. You can use things like $A(v+w)=Av+Aw$ along the way (you are working with linear maps, after all). The first one isn't any different from showing that composing functions is associative. Frankly, I'd say don't think to hard and follow where the symbols lead when you put them down on paper.

Answer (score 3):

The sum of two maps is defined element-wise, 
$$(S+T)\vec v:= S\vec v+ T\vec v$$
where $+$ in RHS is the sum of vectors defined in $V$.
For every vector $\vec v\in V$, you get

$$S(T+U)v=S(T\vec v +U\vec v)=ST\vec v+ SU\vec v=(ST+SU)\vec v$$

Associativity holds in general for functions, not only for linear maps.